# How to filter record in a table with different condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause

How to find the record in a table which as only 'Return' as Reason?

I have table which has many records

[image: This is Table Data]

As per the data in the table, **it returns only records with policy number `5555`, because only that policy number has only `'Return'`**; all other policy numbers have both `'Return'` and `'Success'` which I don't need.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE REASON = 'RETURN'
AND POLICYNUMBER NOT IN (
    SELECT POLICYNUMBER
    FROM YOURTABLE
    WHERE REASON = 'SUCCESS'
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I am looking

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.policynumber = t.policynumber and t1.reason <> 'Return'
)
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `(policynumber, reason)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: @user613400: `not exists` usually scales better than `not in` when the list of values gets bigger. Also, it properly handles `null` values (here, in column `reason`), while `not in` produces weird results if any value in the list is `null`.